# Substituting maple syrup for honey in bread

Tags: substitutions, bread

I've got the following recipe for a honey whole wheat bread-machine bread:

```
1-1/3 cups warm water
1/2 cup honey
3 tablespoons butter
2-2/3 cups whole wheat flour
1-1/3 cups bread flour
1-1/4 tsp salt
2 tsp yeast
```

I'd like to substitute maple syrup for the honey to produce a maple wheat bread.  Can I substitute one for one, or do I need to make adjustments?  In particular, will I need to increase or decrease the amount of water used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple syrup is typically around 1 part water to 2 parts sugar (and a negligible amount of other compounds). Honey is around 1 part water to 5 parts sugar.

This means your recipe includes 5/12 cup sugar and 17/12 cup water.

You would therefore want to add 5/8 cup of maple syrup and 29/24 (roughly 1 1/4) cups of water

None of this needs to be exact. To summarise, I would add a splash more maple syrup and a splash less water than you would if using honey

Answer (score 4):

It's a good deal more simple than @canardgras makes it sound. [I've had good success with the rule](https://www.tablespoon.com/posts/how-to-sweeten-with-maple-syrup):

> To substitute maple syrup for honey in a recipe, use 3/4 cup of maple
>   syrup and 1/2 cup sugar for every 1 cup of honey.

To get half a cup of honey (at a 3/4 ratio) you will want 1/3 of a cup + 1 tablespoon. (for most of us a 5/12 scoop isn't in the cupboard)

Remember two important factors:
 1. This is for REAL Maple Syrup (Imitation Syrup will work, it just has a different ratio)
 2. Maple syrup has more moisture so baking time will vary (be extended).

Comment: this isn't a substitution with just maple syrup though, which i imagine is what OP was looking for. my substitution a) includes no other ingredients, b) take moisture content into account so cooking time will not be affected. c) includes more maple syrup, meaning the flavour will come through better. 5/8 cup is easy enough to estimate, as is 1 1/4 cups water, and i think the fact the cooking time is not affected offsets the minor additional complexity of estimating these quantities

Comment: OP's question included "_do I need to make other adjustments_" which could easily include adding a common ingredient (ie sugar) or tweaking the bake time or temperature.